# Rspec test helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am having a hard time figuring out how to test this helper because `current_group` is not defined in my test case and I am not sure how I can stub it.

```
module Admin
  module EmployeesHelper
    def upload_access
      policy(current_group).can_bulk_create_employees?
    end

    def dashboard_params
      download_employee_url = upload_access ?
        download_admin_group_employees_import_csv_index_path(current_group) : nil
      upload_employee_url = upload_access ?
        admin_group_employees_import_csv_index_path(current_group) : nil
      make_hash(upload_employee_url, download_employee_url)
    end

    private

    def make_hash(upload_url, download_url)
      { 
        employees: @employees,
        addEmployeeUrl: new_admin_group_employee_path(current_group),
        terminated_employees: @terminated_employees,
        new_employees: @new_employees,
        test_employees: @test_employees,
        group_id: current_group.id,
        downloadEmployeeUrl: download_url,
        uploadEmployeeUrl: upload_url
      } 
    end
  end
end
```

Here's what my test looks like, but it fails because `current_group` is not defined.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Admin::EmployeesHelper do
  let!(:group) { create(:group) }

  before do
    # This stub doesn't work because helper doesn't implement current_group 
    allow(helper).to receive(:current_group).and_return(group)
  end

  it 'returns correct dashboard props' do
    allow(helper).to receive(:upload_access).and_return(true)
    props = helper.dashboard_params
    expect(props).values_at(:downloadEmployeeUrl, :uploadEmployeeUrl).should_not include(nil)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only with `current_group` method, you could include this helper in a dummy class. Something like this:

```
let(:klass) {
  Class.new do
    include Admin::EmployeesHelper

    def current_group
      nil
    end
  end
}

let(:instance) { klass.new }

before do 
  allow(instance).to receive(:current_group).and_return('whatever') # test-specific group
end

it 'returns correct dashboard props' do
  allow(instance).to receive(:upload_access).and_return(true)
  props = instance.dashboard_params
  expect(props).values_at(:downloadEmployeeUrl, :uploadEmployeeUrl).should_not include(nil)
end
```

Although I foresee that you'll have to include something for the url helpers too. And set up those instance vars. All in all, it probably isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring the helper to have `current_group` as an argument instead.